# Sort based on two attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to sort the xml first based on the `InfoNo` attribute then `SeqNo` attribute using xsl using templates. I tried in xsl but I can do only on one attribute

Input xml:

```
      <Customer>
          <Info InfoNo="2" SeqNo="1" >
                <LastName>Wilson</LastName>
                <GivenName>Kelley</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="4" SeqNo="1" >
                <LastName>Graham</LastName>
                <GivenName>Tom</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="3" >
                <LastName>Fisher</LastName>
                <GivenName>Elaine</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="2" ">
                <LastName>Gary</LastName>
                <GivenName>Jerry</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="1" >
                <LastName>Timothy</LastName>
                <GivenName>Kathy</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="3" SeqNo="1" >
                <LastName>Tim</LastName>
                <GivenName>Kerry</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="4" >
                <LastName>Rob</LastName>
                <GivenName>Tony</GivenName>
          </Info>
       </Customer>
```

Expected Output xml:

```
    <Customer>
          <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="1" >
                <LastName>Timothy</LastName>
                <GivenName>Kathy</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="2" ">
                <LastName>Gary</LastName>
                <GivenName>Jerry</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="3" >
                <LastName>Fisher</LastName>
                <GivenName>Elaine</GivenName>
          </Info>   
          <Info InfoNo="1" SeqNo="4" >
                <LastName>Rob</LastName>
                <GivenName>Tony</GivenName>
          </Info>                 
          <Info InfoNo="2" SeqNo="1" >
                <LastName>Wilson</LastName>
                <GivenName>Kelley</GivenName>
          </Info>
          <Info InfoNo="3" SeqNo="1" >
                <LastName>Tim</LastName>
                <GivenName>Kerry</GivenName>
          </Info>                 
          <Info InfoNo="4" SeqNo="1" >
                <LastName>Graham</LastName>
                <GivenName>Tom</GivenName>
          </Info>
       </Customer>
```

Need it in xslt1.0

Comment: "I tried in xsl but I can do only on one attribute": So why can't you write two `xsl:sort`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `<xsl:sort>`s for this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/Customer">
   <Customer>
     <xsl:for-each select="Info">
       <xsl:sort select="@InfoNo" data-type="number" />
       <xsl:sort select="@SeqNo" data-type="number" />
       <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </xsl:for-each>
   </Customer>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```